# How to extract elements from nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

1.I need to get the value for business' name and append it to a list.

2.I need to get the value policies and append to a list after checking parent.

3.if parent is Marketing name has to added to level1.

4.if parent is Advertising name has to added to level2.

5.if some place Business is [] I need to pass None instead of Null List

6. Also need to check key exists or not for some keys there is a chance of missing policies, business

Sample dictionary is below

```
searchtest = [{'_index': 'newtest',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '100',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '100',
   'name': 'A',
   'Business': [{'id': '7', 'name': 'Enterprise'},
    {'id': '8', 'name': 'Customer'}],
   'policies': [{'id': '332',
     'name': 'Second division',
     'parent': 'Marketing'},
    {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Marketing'}]}},
 {'_index': 'newtest',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '101',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '101',
   'name': 'B',
   'Business': [{'id': '7'},
    {'id': '8', 'name': 'Customer'}],
   'policies': [{'id': '332',
     'name': 'Second division',
     'parent': 'Marketing'},
    {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Marketing'}]}}]
```

Expected out

```
[
  {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "A",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [ ]
  },
  {
    "id": "101",
    "name": "B",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [ ]
  }
]
```

COde is below

```
def do_the_thing(lst):
    resp = []

    parents_mapper = {
        'Marketing': 'level1',
        'Advertising': 'level2'
    }

    for el in lst:
        d = {
            'id': el['_source']['id'],
            'name': el['_source']['name'],
            'Business': [],
            'level1': [],
            'level2': []
        }
        for business in el.get("_source", {}).get("business", {}).get("name", ""):
            business_name = business.get('name')
            if business_name:
                d['Business'].append(business_name)

        for policy in el.get('policies', []):
            policy_parent = policy.get('parent')
            parent_found = parents_mapper.get(policy_parent)
            policy_name = policy.get('name')
            if parent_found and policy_name:
                d[parent_found].append(policy_name)

        resp.append(d)
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(do_the_thing(searchtest))
```

My output

```
[   {'Business': [], 'id': '100', 'level1': [], 'level2': [], 'name': 'A'},
    {'Business': [], 'id': '101', 'level1': [], 'level2': [], 'name': 'B'}]
```

The problem in my output you can see:
'Business', 'level1' is `[]` is null list.

Adding one more dictionary for testing

```
searchtest = [{'_index': 'newtest',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '100',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '100',
   'name': 'A',
   'policies': [{'id': '332',
     'name': 'Second division',
     'parent': 'Marketing'},
    {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Marketing'}]}},
 {'_index': 'newtest',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '101',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '101',
   'name': 'B',
   'Business': [{'id': '9'}, {'id': '10', 'name': 'Customer'}],
   'policies': [{'id': '332',
     'name': 'Second division',
     'parent': 'Marketing'},
    {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Advertising'}]}}]
```

- In the above dictionary you can see that there is no Business in 100 key and  for 101 there is no name inside the Business key. So there will be key error will be coming. Need to handle that

Comment: If you debug (just by placing print statements in several places), you can discover what went wrong. As far as I can tell, your two inner for loops are never run

Comment: By the way, this looks like json, so maybe you can use the json library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not collecting data from dict, You have to select particular key to get it's value.

replace this :

```
for el in lst:
        d = {
            'id': el['_source']['id'],
            'name': el['_source']['name'],
            'Business': [],
            'level1': [],
            'level2': []
        }
```

with this:

```
for el in data:
        d = {
            'id'       : el['_source']['id'],
            'name'     : el['_source']['name'],
            'Business' : [name['name'] for name in el['_source']['Business']],
            'level1'    : [name['name'] for name in el['_source']['policies']],
            'level2'   : []
        }
```

output:

```
[   {   'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
        'id': '100',
        'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
        'level2': [],
        'name': 'A'},
    {   'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
        'id': '101',
        'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
        'level2': [],
        'name': 'B'}]
```

Comment: I got key error KeyError: 'name'
Business' : [name['name'] for name in el['_source']['Business']],

Comment: I haved edited the dictionary. can you check once ??